# Android Studio stuck on splash screen

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Yesterday, when I opened Android Studio, it got stuck on the loading screen. and does not enter the program, I closed and opened the task manager many times and even uninstalled and installed it but it didn't work.

Inside the task manager, it is only running in the background Process

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWL9A.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Instead please add some more information for example about your operating system.